# How to setup WPF parent/child listboxes

Tags: wpf, xml, binding, listbox

I need selected item of Listbox1 to provide XmlDataprovider source for second Listbox.

Listbox1 uses:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="CategoryXML"
                 Source="C:\Category.xml"
                 XPath="category"
                 />
```

Ex: Category.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<main>
<category>
    <name>Local</name>
    <XmlFileName>C:\Doc1.xml</XmlFileName>
</category>
<category>
    <name>National</name>
    <XmlFileName>C:\Doc2.xml</XmlFileName>
</category>
<category>
    <name>Global</name>
    <XmlFileName>C:\Doc3.xml</XmlFileName>
</category>
</main>
```

xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CategoryXML},XPath=//main//category}"
         SynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Name="CategoryList">
```

ListBox2:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="itemXML"
                 Source="?" **XmlFileName of select item in Listbox1**
                 XPath="item"
                 />
```

The problem I'm having is finding the correct syntax for making XmlFileName the source for itemXML. The user will select the `<name>` in ListBox1 and send the `<XmlFileName>` to itemXML which feeds Listbox2

Comment: Tip: XML (and XAML) tags won't show up in normal text because SO treats them as HTML tags (and the browser silently doesn't render them because it doesn't recognise them).  Use backticks or the code (101010) button to make them show up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can do it through ordinary data binding.  But it's easy with a little code-behind:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Master" Source="Master.xml" XPath="Master/Item"/>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Detail" XPath="Detail/Item"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox 
            Name="MasterList"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Master}}"
            SelectionChanged="MasterList_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=Description}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Name="DetailList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Detail}}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=Description, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And then:

```
private void MasterList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
    XmlElement elm = lb.SelectedItem as XmlElement;
    string filename = elm.SelectSingleNode("Filename").InnerText;
    XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
    d.Load(filename);
    XmlDataProvider p = Resources["Detail"] as XmlDataProvider;
    p.Document = d;
}
```

This works because an `XmlDataProvider` refreshes whenever you set its `Document` property.  You could also just construct a URI from the filename and set the `Source` property; that refreshes it too.